# system-config-lvm will be removed if i install Playonlinux?

Tags: installation, wine, package-management, lvm

When i try to install Playonlinux, I am told (by synaptic, as well as the "Software Center") that `system-config-lvm` will be removed, does anyone know why?

Comment: Does this error appear only when you try installing Playonlinux or for all other packages?

Comment: its just for Playonlinux

Comment: btw i'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: i've looked into this problem myself for the past couple days, and it seems that this is a dependency issue having to do with the "gettext" package, anyway i have worked around the problem by first completely uninstalling system-config-lvm, installing playonlinux, and then reinstalling system-config-lvm

Comment: Can you add the workaround as a answer to this question. So it will be helpful for others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

i've looked into this problem myself for the past couple days, and it seems that this is a dependency issue having to do with the "gettext" package, anyway i have worked around the problem by first completely uninstalling system-config-lvm, installing playonlinux, and then reinstalling system-config-lvm